# Why is there no air blowing from ac inside house?

Tags: hvac

I changed my filter and the next day the AC had stopped blowing air. The unit outside fan is running and I can hear the AC unit inside like it's going to come on but nothing happens. I switched to just fan on and it doesn't come on. I also had a power outage the same day, and it jumped on for a few seconds and right back off; could that have made it stop working?

Comment: It sounds like the start capacitor for the fan is gone.  Think it is a simple fix that should not cost too much.

Comment: Did you check the breakers for the ir handler?

Answer (score 3):

On most homes, there are two completely different systems involved in A/C.

The FURNACE has a gas heater.  It also has an "Air Handling Stack". That consists of a filter, a blower, an air/air heat exchanger (which transfers the heat, but not the carbon monoxide), ***Optional Stuff Here***, then a maze of vents going to each room.

It's called a stack because of those optional things that can be stacked on.

- humidifier
- advanced air filters
- air conditioner condenser

The AIR CONDITIONER is an *optional feature*. It relies on the furnace's blower to push cold air though its duct system.  As such, the furnace is built with a separate control pin (G) to allow the thermostat to call for "fan only".

The furnace has no idea that an A/C system exists.

The thermostat's job is to coordinate the two.  When it wants A/C, it asks the furnace for fan, AND ALSO asks the A/C for cooling.

Understand so far?  What does this tell you?

Yeah. The outside A/C unit is answering the call for cool, but the furnace is not *answering* the call for fan.

- Either the thermostat is not making the call,
- or the furnace is not hearing the call,
- or the furnace is trying to answer the call but is broken.

The call for fan is done by the thermostat shunting (i.e. shorting) Rh and G control wires together. This should be 24-volt low voltage power, so it isn't dangerous. Read up a bit on how thermostats work, then feel free to do some testing.

Answer (score 2):

If the new filter came wrapped in plastic, perhaps you forgot to remove the plastic before you installed it. You should check to see that the filter is not still wrapped.

If that's what happened, your evaporator is probably a block of solid frost now. To melt the frost and restore air flow, turn the thermostat to a temperature higher than room temperature and turn the thermostat's fan control to ON instead of AUTO. It will take several hours of constant fan to melt the frost, during which time you will start to feel air blowing from the registers. When the air reaches full force and the frost is melted, you can resume normal air conditioning.

Comment: Spottable by the condensate pan no longer dripping water.